# XPath extract text within several same div tag

Tags: php, xpath

I have this html and i wish to extract the text `bla bla bla` and `bla3 bla3 bla3`.

So far i have try this

```
//div[@class="s1"]//ul[@class="a1"]//text()[1]')->item(0)->nodeValue;
```

but it's not working.

```
<div class="s1">
    <ul class="a1">bla bla bla</ul>
    <ul class="a1">bla2 bla2 bla2</ul> 
</div>

<div class="s1">
    <ul class="a1">bla3 bla3 bla3</ul>
    <ul class="a1">bla4 bla4 bla4</ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

For your example, you can use the XPath

```
concat(
 (//div[@class='s1']//ul[@class='a1'][1])[1],
 (//div[@class='s1']//ul[@class='a1'][1])[2]
)
```

which gives

```
bla bla blabla3 bla3 bla3
```

But you probably already know that, and want to do this for an unknown number of elements.

Unfortunately, I don't think that is possible in pure XPath, that is, automatically concatenating the text of multiple nodes.  I encountered a similar situation recently and ended up using a loop to concatenate.

**UPDATE:** If you have XQuery available, this is easy:

```
for $x in //div[@class="s1"]//ul[@class="a1"][1] return $x/text()
```

If you need a space between the strings, you can use

```
for $x in //div[@class="s1"]//ul[@class="a1"][1] return concat($x, " ")
```

Comment: can i use query to do so?

Answer (score 1):

You don't say in the question what tool, library or application you're using to evaluate your XPath expressions but your mention of `->item(0)->nodeValue` suggests you're working with a standard DOM tree in some language or other.  So what you need to do is use XPath to extract the first `ul class="a1"` inside each `div class="s1"`, and then take that DOM element's `textContent` (*not* `nodeValue`, which is null by definition for element nodes).

The XPath you need would be something like

```
//div[@class="s1"]/ul[@class="a1"][1]
```

Evaluating that will give you a node list containing `ul` element nodes, one for each matching `div`, so you then iterate over that list in whatever way your library provides and take the `textContent` of each node.

Edit: for PHP DOMXPath that would be something like

```php
$nodelist = $xpath->query('//div[@class="s1"]/ul[@class="a1"][1]');
foreach($nodelist as $node) {
  echo $node->textContent . "\n";
}
```

Comment: im using xpath query in php